# How to find the general solution of this equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$$y'=(xy'+y)y^3$$
I don't know how to approach this problem with the two $y'$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move all $y'$ terms to one side:
$$\begin{align}y'&=(xy'+y)y^3\\y'&=xy^3y'+y^4\\y'-xy^3y'&=y^4\\y'(1-xy^3)&=y^4\\y'&=\frac{y^4}{1-xy^3}\end{align}$$
Does this get you closer to a form that you know how to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $xy' + y = (xy)'$, which means that $\dfrac{y'}{y^3} = (xy)'$. Can you continue?